# I am getting this EOF error when running this bash script

Tags: bash

I am a noob to scripting in bash.

Here are the two errors I keep getting:
line 16: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
line 18: syntax error: unexpected end of file

For line 16 the " is matching
I'm not even sure what is wrong with 18 at all
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script for Capture
# sudo tshark -i2 -f "tcp" -P -S -l -w mbcap.pcap

_now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
_file="~/captures/$_now.pcap"
echo "Starting capture to $_file..."
echo "Creating Output Directory as: $_file
touch $_file
chmod 666 $_file

echo "Which Interface Would you like to capture on:"
sudo tshark -D
read selection

sudo tshark -i$selection -f "tcp" -P -S -l -w $_file
```

Comment: With errors like that the problem is often not in the line number given. The problem is encountered when the end of file is reached without a close (quote, brace, etc). The problem is usually earlier, where you open a (quote, brace, etc) and forget to close it. Instead of saying "the quote opened in line 8 was never closed" (which would be helpful) you get this. But you can figure it out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a closing `"` on the line where you're outputting:

```
echo "Creating Output Directory as: $_file
```

Comment: Cool, the color-coding hints at that.